# What is $\frac{d(\arctan(x))}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Let $v= \arctan{x}$. Now I want to find $\frac{dv}{dx}$. My method is this: Rearranging yields $\tan(v) = x$ and so $dx = \sec^2(v)dv$. How do I simplify from here? Of course I could do something like $dx = \sec^2(\arctan(x))dv$ so that $\frac{dv}{dx} = \cos^2(\arctan(x))$ but I am sure a better expression exists. I am probably just missing some crucial step where we convert one of the trigonometric expressions into an expression involving $x$. Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The derivative of $\tan v$ is $1+\tan^2 v$. It will be easier to simplify, since here $v=\arctan x$.

You may check:

$$\sec^2 v = \frac{1}{\cos^2 v} = \frac{\cos^2 v + \sin^2 v}{\cos^2 v} = 1+\tan^2 v$$

Then

$$\mathrm{d}x = (1+\tan^2 v) \ \mathrm{d}v = (1+x^2) \ \mathrm{d}v$$

And

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot, this is very clear. I see now that using $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)^2+1}$ will also change the expression $\cos^2(\arctan(x))$ into $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Another way :

$$\frac{d\arctan x}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan x}h$$

$$\displaystyle=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\arctan\frac{x+h-x}{1+(x+h)x}}h$$

$$\displaystyle=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{\arctan\frac h{1+(x+h)x}}{\frac h{1+(x+h)x}}\right)\cdot\frac1{\lim_{h\to0}\{1+(x+h)x\}}=1\cdot\frac1{1+x^2}$$

as $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\arctan u}u=\lim_{v\to0}\frac v{\tan v}=\lim_{v\to0}\cos v\cdot\frac1{\lim_{v\to0}\frac{\sin v}v}=1\cdot1$

Comment: Definition of the derivative! +1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is nice to see how the answer tackle my question in a multitude of ways!

Comment: @Slugger, my pleasure. Please have a look into  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579170/question-about-the-limit-lim-h-to0-frac-arcsinxh-arcsinxh

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [Inverse Derivative Formula](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DiffInvTrigFcns.aspx), which states that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverse functions, we have $$ g'(x) = \dfrac {1}{f'(g(x))}. $$So, if $g(x)=\arctan x$, our task is to find $g'(x)$. In that case, we have $f(x)=\tan x$, which gives us $f'(x)=sec^2 x$, so we can substitute: $$ \begin {align*} g'(x) &= \dfrac {1}{f'(g(x))} \\&= \dfrac {1}{\sec^2 (g(x))} \\&= \dfrac {1}{\sec^2 (\arctan x)}. \end {align*} $$We can find $ \sec (\arctan x) $ geometrically. Consider a right triangle with legs of length $x$, $1$, and $\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Let $\theta$ be the angle opposite to the leg of length $x$. Then, $$ \sec \left( \arctan x \right) = \sec (\theta) = \sqrt {1+x^2}, $$ so our answer is $$ \dfrac {1}{\left( \sqrt{1+x^2} \right)^2} = \boxed {\dfrac {1}{1+x^2}}. $$

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

$$v=\arctan(x)\Rightarrow x=\tan v\Rightarrow x'=\frac{1}{(\tan v)'}=\frac{1}{(\frac{\sin v}{\cos v})'}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos^2 v}}=\cos^2 v=\frac{\cos^2 v}{1}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2 v}{\cos^2 v+\sin^2 v}=\frac{\frac{\cos^2 v}{\cos^2 v}}{\frac{\cos^2 v+\sin^2 v}{\cos^2 v}}=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 v}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
i.e
$$v'=(\arctan(x))'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: I am not sure I follow exactly. Your second equation says $x=\tan v$ and then you follow by saying $x' =\frac{1}{(\tan v)'}$... Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Sir, my solution is correct, You can also use the Inverse Derivative Formula,

Comment: Oh, it seems this is essentially what I did, but I posted a few minutes later. I didn't see your post when I posted, so it's not that I copied. Should I delete my post?

Comment: I am sure it is correct, it is just that I am do not understand one of the steps. Nonetheless, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MadritZhaku When somebody asks you to explain what you did, "it is correct" is not as helpful as actually explaining what you did. If you don't have the patience to elaborate, don't respond at all. Your comment came off quite rude.

Comment: @Slugger I admire your patience. To explain that step, I'd say he's just using the Inverse Derivative Formula which I linked you to in my answer. I agree it is not clear.

Comment: @ Ahaan Rungta  no, must be deleted your solution, and you have given a good solution

Comment: @MadritZhaku Sorry, what are you saying? I can't quite comprehend? Should I delete my post or not?

Comment: Sir, I think your answer is very good

Comment: all is well that ends well :)

Comment: I think my answer is very clear, ie to understand the need to know Inverse Derivative Formula, also that $\cos^2 x=\frac{1}{\tan^ x} $