# How can I compute this limit without L'Hôpital's rule: $x$ approaches zero for $\arcsin(x^2)/x^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I think I can evaluate it with a substitution but not sure about the passages.

Comment: I'm not feeling the inspiration either.

Comment: yes, I can't do it. Otherwise, I would not ask here.

Comment: Are you supposed to use geometry?

Comment: no, don't think so...

Comment: Let $u=\arcsin(x^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517704/limit-lim-x-to0-1-tan9x-frac1-arcsin5x/1520012#1520012), I showed using standard, non-calculus-based tools that the arcsine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\le \arcsin x\le \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Therefore, we have

$$x^2 \le \arcsin(x^2)\le \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

whereupon dividing both sides by $x^2$ yields

$$1 \le \frac{\arcsin(x^2)}{x^2}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

Now applying the squeeze theorem, we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin(x^2)}{x^2}=1$$

---

Alternatively, we could have enforced the substitution $x^2=\sin y$.  Therefore

$$\frac{\arcsin(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{y}{\sin y}$$

and since $\lim_{x\to 0}y=0$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin(x^2)}{x^2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\sin y}=1$$

Comment: thank you! It is interesting, really! But I think I should proceed in another, simpler, way. There should be another way just using algebraic manipulation!

Comment: You're welcome.  I just added a note with a simpler way.

Comment: but arcsin isn't 1/sin, that is csc

Comment: $\arcsin (x^2)= \arcsin (\sin y)=y$ when $x^2=\sin y$