# Is this series divergent or convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Please explain what method you used to prove so.
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{n}$$

Comment: Convergent, since they approach $\sum \pi/n^2$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$

Comment: oh ok so you used the comparison test. The thing is that I wasn't sure if I should use that test because I didn't know if the series would always contain positive terms.

Comment: Convergent. The general term behaves like $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Looks like you guys are using $tan(x) \sim x$

Comment: Not sure it contains positive terms?  With $0<\frac\pi n\le \frac\pi 3$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\tan(x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517704/limit-lim-x-to0-1-tan9x-frac1-arcsin5x/1520012#1520012), I showed using elementary inequalities from geometry that the tangent function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\le \tan(x)\le x\sec(x) \tag 1$$

for $0\le x<\pi/2$.  Therefore, using $(1)$ we find for $n\ge 3$

$$\left|\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{n}\right|\le \frac{\pi}{n^2}\sec(\pi/n)\le \frac{2\pi }{n^2}$$

since the secant function on $[0,\pi/3]$ attains its maximum at $\pi/3$

Finally, using $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we see that the series of interest converges and is in fact, less than $\pi^3/3$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark