# Calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n \cdot \tan \left( \frac{3}{2n+2} \right)\right)$

Tags: limits

Calculate limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n \cdot \tan \left( \frac{3}{2n+2} \right)\right)$$
every suggestion by every way will be grateful.

Comment: The limit is $1$, simply by using the approximation $\tan x \sim x$ around $0$.

Comment: Are you asking what my contribution to solving the problem was? I am unable to calculate the limit mentioned..

Comment: Are $t,g$ constants (or $tg$ one constant), or do you mean $\tan$?

Comment: Yes,thank you for correcting me!

Comment: @Arthur It's actually $3/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I thought that it would be instructive to present a solution that relies only on inequalities that can be obtained without calculus. To that end, we proceed.**

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517704/limit-lim-x-to0-1-tan9x-frac1-arcsin5x/1520012#1520012), I showed that the tangent function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$x\le \tan(x)\le \frac{x}{\cos(x)} \tag 1$$
>
> for $0<x<\pi/2$, by simply rearranging the well-known inequalities from elementary geometry, $x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2$.

---

Using $(1)$, we have

$$\frac{3n}{2n+2}\le n\tan\left(\frac{3}{2n+2}\right)\le \frac{3n}{(2n+2)\cos\left(\frac{3}{2n+2}\right)}$$

whereupon using the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\tan\left(\frac{3n}{2n+2}\right)=\frac32$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Assuming $tg$ means $\tan$, then we have that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\cdot \tan\frac{3}{2n+2} =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\cdot \sin\frac{3}{2n+2} \sec \frac{3}{2n+2}\\
=&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3n(2n+2)}{3(2n+2)}\cdot \sin\frac{3}{2n+2} \cdot \sec \frac{3}{2n+2}\\
=&\  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3n}{(2n+2)}\cdot \frac{\sin\frac{3}{2n+2}}{\frac{3}{2n+2}}\cdot \sec \frac{3}{2n+2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, tg stands for tan. Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Shortly $$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } n\cdot \tan { \left( \frac { 3 }{ 2n+2 }  \right)  } =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { \tan { \left( \frac { 3 }{ 2n+2 }  \right)  }  }{ \frac { 3 }{ 2n+2 }  } \cdot \frac { 3n }{ 2n+2 } =\frac { 3 }{ 2 } \\ \\  $$