# Prove the following inequations

Tags: analysis, inequality

> Prove the following:
>
> **1)** $∀x \in [0,1]$:     $ x ≤ \arcsin(x) $≤ $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1−x^2}}$
>
> **2)** $∀a,b \in  {\displaystyle \mathbb {R_+} }$ : $a < b$   $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{b-a}{b} < log\left(\frac ba\right) < \frac {b-a}a $

I thought about it and still don't know where to start.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hint for second inequality: Consider the function $\f(x)=\ln x$ and use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral representation of the arcsine function is given by

$$\arcsin(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt \tag 1$$

If $t\in [0,x]$, and $1>x\ge 0$, then we have

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}\le\sqrt{1-t^2}\le 1\tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we see that for $1>x\ge 0$

$$x\le \arcsin(x)\le \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

---

The integral representation of the logarithm function is given by

$$\log(x) =\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

for $x>0$.

Hence, we have for $0<a<b$

$$\log(b/a)=\int_a^b \frac1t\,dt \tag 3$$

Clearly, for $0<a<t<b$, we have form $(3)$

$$\frac{b-a}{b}<\log(b/a)<\frac{b-a}{a}$$

---

**PRE-CALCULUS APPROACH:**

I though it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on elementary, pre-calculus tools only.  To that end, we proceed.

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I used only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality to show that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 \tag4$$

Letting $x=b/a$ yields the coveted result

$$\frac{b-a}{b}\le \log(b/a)\le \frac{b-a}{a}$$

And in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517704/limit-lim-x-to0-1-tan9x-frac1-arcsin5x/1520012#1520012), I used the well-known inequalities

$$x\le \sin(x)\le x\cos(x)$$

for $x\in [-\pi/2,0]$ from elementary geometry to show that the arcsine function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \le \arcsin(x)\le x$$

for $x\in (-1,0)$.  Exploiting the odd symmetry we see immediately that for $x\in (0,1)$ satisfies the inequalities

$$x\le \arcsin(x)\le \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Is it possible to prove that without integrals ? I know that's stupid but i will have integrals in the next week.

Comment: It is possible.  I've edited to add a pre-calculus approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Let $x =\sin t$.

So you need to prove that

$$\sin t \le t \le \tan t$$

Can you do that? (Using derivatives)