# Derivative of $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

I was trying to find the derivative of 
$$\arcsin(x) = \sin^{-1}(x)$$

I thought that I could use the rule of inversion:

$$({f^{-1}})'(x) = \dfrac{1}{f(x)'}$$

Therefor the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ should be:
$$\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}$$

[image]

But for some reason, this seems to only work for small $x$. Where did I do a mistake?

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: You already got your answer. I just want to mention that the reason the two graphs look the same for small $x$ is that, incidentally,
$$
\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+\mathcal O(x^4)
$$
where $\mathcal O$ stands for Landau's [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579170/question-about-the-limit-lim-h-to0-frac-arcsinxh-arcsinxh and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533369/derivative-of-sin-1x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of $\sin^{-1}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533369/derivative-of-sin-1x)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the rule is$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac1{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)}$$and therefore\begin{align}\arcsin'(x)&=\frac1{\cos\bigl(\arcsin(x)\bigr)}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\bigl(\arcsin(x)\bigr)}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.\end{align}

Comment: Oh... I see what I mixed up. I messed up with the "y" and "x". Thank you! :)

Comment: @FinnEggers I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

with $$sin(y)=x$$ we get $$\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cos(y)}$$ therefore $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 5):

In fact, we have

$ (\arcsin x)' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

since,$(f^{-1}(x))' = \dfrac 1{f'(y)}$

Answer (score 4):

You could use the correct formula of inversion:
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac 1{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)}.$$
In other words, if you set $y=f^{-1}(x)$, then 
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac 1{f'(\color{red}{y})}.$$
Here you obtain
$$\arcsin' x=\frac1{\cos(\arcsin x)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$$
because of *Pythagoras' identity* and $-\frac\pi2\le\arcsin x\le \frac\pi2$, so the cosine is $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier to apply the definition of arcsine:
$$
x=\sin(\arcsin(x))
$$
The “rule of inversion” ensures you that the derivative of the arcsine exists (with a condition that I'll deal with later) so you can differentiate both sides using the chain rule:
$$
1=\cos(\arcsin(x))\arcsin'(x)
$$
Therefore
$$
\arcsin'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin(x))}
$$
The condition I mentioned above is, of course, that $\cos(\arcsin(x))\ne0$.

Now we just have to simplify $\cos(\arcsin(x))$; use the fact that $\arcsin(x)\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, so
$$
\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))}=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
Thus
$$
\arcsin'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\qquad x\in(-1,1)
$$